# How do I securely get data transferred from C to Perl?

Tags: c, perl, variables

Suppose I have a perl program such as:

```
my $c = "MyDataToCProg";
open my $h, '-|', 'myCProg', "$c";
my @result = <$h>;
close $h;
print "Result: " . $result[0] . "\n";
```

Now, myCProg is a program compiled with gcc. The C program's output would be a printf statement which would end up in the perl program's $result[0] variable.

Is there a better way to extract output out of a C program than through printing with printf? For example, anyone could also run 'myCProg' from the command line and also see output. I want the output to only be seen in the perl program an NOT viewable if someone ran the program at the command line.

Anyone know how to do this?

Sorry, I don't have a C Program handy, but anything that has a printf statement (even a simple Hello World) and takes an argument (maybe prints "Hello [yourname]" would work for this example.

Comment: [Inline::C](http://p3rl.org/Inline::C)?

Comment: or change the permissions on `myCProg` so only folks with permission to execute it can.

Comment: @thrig, You'd have to make the Perl script an set-uid script for that to be useful.

Comment: I completely fail to see what setuid on a perl script would have to do with controlling who has permissions to execute `myCProg`, e.g. `chmod go-rwx myCProg` to restrict execution (and thus viewing the output) to just the owner.

Comment: @thrig 1. create user to own `myPerlProg` and `myCProg`.  2. `chmod 700 myCProg`.  3. make `myPerlProg` setuid so other users can execute `myPerlProg` and it can execute `myCProg` (but they can't execute `myCProg` directly).

Comment: @thrig, If you do that, the user won't be able to execute it, but the OP wants the user to be able to execute it. He just doesn't want the user to see its output. So changing the permissions of the C program isn't enough. You additionally have to make the Perl script a set-uid script.

Comment: If we're talking permissions, both the myCProg and perl script will be chmod 700 and owned/group root. The perl script will also have code in it that will not let it run unless it's run by root or sudo (double checks and if not then it will print to console that it must be run by root). I'm wondering, is all this enough? Also I heard that anything printed to console is stored somewhere and can be recalled (like in a profile cache). I want the output of the C Program to not end up in one of these caches.

Comment: Wait... I think I was wrong about caching output. I remembered that things you type in at the command line can be cached in the profile (so that you can use the up arrow to recall them) but not anything printed out to the screen by a program. I assume this is true?

Comment: Nope, still not seeing where the setuid is coming from. Maybe the poster could clarify the requirements?

Comment: @thrig, see my last two comments. I don't know how else to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

You could encrypt the communication. You could communicate via fd 3. You could create a socket and have the C program connect to that socket. But whatever you do can be done by anyone else too.

The only solution that comes to mind involves file permissions: Remove the ability to access the C program, and make the Perl program a set-uid script whose owner has access to the C program. In detail,

1. Create a user to own this application. Let's call it `myProg`.
2. `chown myProg myCProg myPerlProg`
3. `chmod 700 myCProg`
4. `chmod 4755 myPerlProg`

Comment: Besides wondering why setuid has been proposed as a solution to this problem (perhaps the poster could clarify what exactly "anyone could also run" means?), I could point out that suidperl support was eliminated from perl five years ago (`perldoc perl5120delta`). Thus, the above is certainly not a valid solution.

Comment: @thrig, Perhaps you should read your own reference, cause you are completely wrong. What was removed from 5.12 was an emulation of setuid scripts for systems that didn't support them. Setuid Perl scripts still work on systems that support setuid scripts.